# Cause of Error Message "Error:(27) Tag <manifest> attribute package has invalid type 4."

Tags: android, android-studio, manifest

When trying to build my app, I get the following error message:  "Error:(27) Tag <manifest> attribute package has invalid type 4."  Any ideas on what is causing this?  Here is a copy of my manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.dummy.tanc">

    <application
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:fullBackupContent="false"                        
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.games.APP_ID"
            android:value="@string/app_id" />
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
                   android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>

        <activity
            android:name="com.google.example.games.tanc.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because, in your manifest, you've set your package name (line 2) to be

```
package="com.dummy.tanc"
```

and in when defining the activity (line 18), you've used

```
android:name="com.google.example.games.tanc.MainActivity"
```

Because of this mismatch, the issue could be arising. Change the line 18 to

```
android:name="com.dummy.tanc.MainActivity"
```

Answer (score 0):

It means attribute package has type float but not string.

I guess your package name contains only numbers, something like `package="1.0"`.